# VS 2012 Mid funktion (get part of a html code)

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012

I started to make a little app with VS 2012.
The app should download html code and should just copy a little part of the webpage.
Normally I use the 'Mid function', but in VS 2012 I can't find it.
Does anybody know how I could get a specific part of an webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [`string.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)

Like:

```
string onlyAPart = downloadedwebpageasstring.Substring(20, 5);
```

For example to take 5 characters starting from the 20th character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a function to extract a portion of a string, you might take a look at the Substring method. It's a standard method of the String object in .NET